# ValueError: Unknown solver interior-point

Tags: python, optimization

I'm using python 3.5.4 in Anaconda 5.0.0. I tried to run following optimization code

```
z=scipy.optimize.linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, bounds=bounds,method='interior-point',
                         options = {"maxiter":10000})
```

I'm getting these error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-60df6b13e821>", line 3, in <module>
    options = {"maxiter":10000})

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_linprog.py", line 995, in linprog
    raise ValueError('Unknown solver %s' % method)

ValueError: Unknown solver interior-point
```

Kindly suggest me what should I do to resolve these issue

Comment: What is your scipy version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Scipy 1.0.0 emerged the "interior-point" method.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.0.0.html

Probably your current version is older.

You should update scipy in Anaconda.